# how to get videos from amazon s3 in to my hwdVideoShare component or hdflvplayer component?

Tags: joomla

how to get videos from amazon s3  in to my hwdVideoShare component or hdflvplayer component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is not possible, if u want get amazon s3 videos u must upgrade your it is not possible, if u want get amazon s3 videos u must upgrade your hdflvplayer in proversion.

Answer (score 0):

This Option is available with free version of Contus HD Video Share for Joomla. So the videos and thumb images that you upload will be saved in Amazon S3 bucket.